# Can son perform a tarpanam to his mother when father is alive

Tags: rituals, sraddha, shraddha

Can the son perform tarpanam and pitru paksha rituals to his dead mother while his father is still alive? Some people say he can perform tarpanam to his mother, grandmother, great grandmother only not for others, whereas some people say a son cannot perform tarpanam to his mother while his father still being alive (even though he has the right to perform and doing shraddha rituals every year).

What do our shastras say on this? Any help would be much appreciated. I am not finding much help on this.

Comment: No a son cannot do tharpanam for his living parents. But, the parents can do their own Shraddha while alive. This is called Atma Shraddha and is highly meritorious act as mentioned in lingapuram chapter 45.

Comment: @Chamundadas You got my question wrong. I am asking about giving tarpanam to dead mother, grandmother and great grandmother. Not to living parents.

Comment: So sorry, my bad, I didn't noticed the word deceased. Irrespective of what one says, tarpan must be done for anyone who is deceased within three generations irrespective of whether the husband or wife is still living. Because pind acts as food for deceased pitras. In that case the pitras  can't be kept hungry and unsatisfied till their better half too leave the body. Pind is the sole mode of nourishment and 'Gati' for them. Thus, unbiasedly tarpanam must be done.